# a sql server error occurred. try this action again

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I've CRM 2011 on-premise installation. When a workflow (both custom and crm workflow) try to a create note in Account entity, an error occurred. When I check the workflow status it shows ‘Waiting’ and showing below error message.

“A SQL Server error occurred.  Try this action again.  If the problem continues check the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Community for solutions or contact your organization's Microsoft Dynamics CRM Administrator.  Finally, you can contact Microsoft Support”

Workflow paused due to error: Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Generic SQL error.Detail:

-2147204784

Generic SQL error.

2012-10-25T11:11:01.2064949Z

```
<ErrorCode>-2147204784</ErrorCode>

<ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />

<Message>Generic SQL error.</Message>

<Timestamp>2012-10-25T11:11:01.2064949Z</Timestamp>

<InnerFault>

  <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>

  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />

  <Message>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #6F1D18EA</Message>

  <Timestamp>2012-10-25T11:11:01.207495Z</Timestamp>

  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />

  <TraceText i:nil="true" />

</InnerFault>

<TraceText i:nil="true" />
```

at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)

at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InprocessServiceProxy.RetrieveMultipleCore(QueryBase query)

at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.RegardingObjectUtility.CreateLookup(String entityName, Guid entityId)

at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.WorkflowContextBase.SetStepRegardingRecord(String entityName, Guid entityId)

at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.UpdateActivityService.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(IOrganizationService sdkService)

at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.ActivityServiceBase.ExecuteInTransactedContext(ActivityDelegate activityDelegate)

at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.UpdateActivityService.UpdateInternal(Entity entity, String stepId)

at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.UpdateActivityService.ExecuteInternal(ActivityContext executionContext, UpdateEntity updateEntity)

at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.UpdateActivityService.Execute(ActivityContext executionContext, UpdateEntity updateEntity)

at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

I checked trace also.

Please suggest,

Thanks

Kiran

Comment: If your question is answered can you please mark it so. StackOverflow works by rewarding other people for finding solutions to your problems ;)

Answer (score 2):

Enable tracing ([using this tool easiest](http://mscrmtools.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/new-tool-crmdiagtool-2011.html)) and take a look at the resulting trace file for the Async service (can't remember the file name but it will have "async" in it somewhere). This should give you some additional detail.

Do you have any plugins registered on your system (especially against the `Account` or `Annotation` (Note) entity?